# Foreign key mismatch in SQLite3

Tags: sql, sqlite, foreign-keys, primary-key

I'm using **SQLite3** for simple application (like agenda). Agenda is multilingual. That's the reason why I have table rooms in more languages (count of languages must be independent)

At first, I have  a table **rooms** with this definition:

```
CREATE TABLE rooms 
(
    room_code VARCHAR2(32),
    lang_code CHAR(2),
    room_name VARCHAR(32),
    PRIMARY KEY (room_code, lang_code),
    FOREIGN KEY (lang_code) REFERENCES languages (lang_code),
    CHECK (LENGTH(lang_code) = 2),
    CHECK (room_code <> '')
);
```

Then I have a table **events** with this definition:

```
CREATE TABLE events 
(
    room_code VARCHAR2(32) NOT NULL,
    message_code VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    time_start DATETIME NOT NULL ,
    time_end DATETIME NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (message_code, room_code),
    FOREIGN KEY (room_code) REFERENCES rooms (room_code),
    -- Check the time is between 00:00 and 23:59
    CHECK (time_start and time_end BETWEEN TIME('00:00') AND TIME('23:59')),
    -- Start time must be lower than end time
    CHECK (time_start < time_end),
    -- Message code cannot be empty
    CHECK (message_code <> '') 
);
```

But in fact, I got this error in any attempt of insert:

```
Error: near line 91: foreign key mismatch - "events" referencing "rooms"
```

Why can I not reference another table? I read that all foreign keys of table B must be PRIMARY KEY in table A. But this dependency is OK for me. Foreign key **room_code** from table **events** it's also primary key **room_code** in table **rooms**.

Is that possible the solution of this instead of **TRIGGERS**? In fact, I want use rather KEYS instead of TRIGGERS if is it possible. Thanks

Best regards

Answer (score 2):

I believe that your issue is due to non conformation with :-

> Usually, the parent key of a foreign key constraint is the primary key
>   of the parent table. If they are not the primary key, then the parent
>   key columns must be collectively subject to a UNIQUE constraint or
>   have a UNIQUE index. If the parent key columns have a UNIQUE index,
>   then that index must use the collation sequences that are specified in
>   the CREATE TABLE statement for the parent table. For example,

**[SQLite Foreign Key Support](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html)**

Note **the primary key** as opposed to part of a primary key.

In short, the column(s) referenced by the foreign key must be known to be unique.

As such you could either add an index for the room_code column or define it to utilise the UNIQUE constraint e.g. :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS events;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS rooms;
DROP INDEX IF EXISTS room_code_idx;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS rooms (
    room_code VARCHAR2(32) UNIQUE, --<<<<<<<<<< ADDED UNIQUE
    lang_code CHAR(2),
    room_name VARCHAR(32),
    PRIMARY KEY (room_code, lang_code),
    -- FOREIGN KEY (lang_code) REFERENCES languages (lang_code)  
    CHECK (LENGTH(lang_code) = 2),
    CHECK (room_code <> '')
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS events (
    room_code VARCHAR2(32) NOT NULL,
    message_code VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    time_start DATETIME NOT NULL ,
    time_end DATETIME NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (message_code, room_code),
    FOREIGN KEY (room_code) REFERENCES rooms (room_code),
    -- Check the time is between 00:00 and 23:59
    CHECK (time_start and time_end BETWEEN TIME('00:00') AND TIME('23:59')),
    -- Start time must be lower than end time
    CHECK (time_start < time_end),
    -- Message code cannot be empty
    CHECK (message_code <> '') 
);

INSERT INTO rooms VALUES('room001','xx','This is room 1');
INSERT INTO events VALUES('room001','This is a message for room 1','01:00','02:00');
```

- Note FK to lang_code commented out for convenience/brevity

results in :-

```
INSERT INTO rooms VALUES('room001','xx','This is room 1')
> Affected rows: 1
> Time: 0.3s


INSERT INTO events VALUES('room001','This is a message for room 1','01:00','02:00')
> Affected rows: 1
> Time: 0.301s
```

Of course, you could just define the PRIMARY KEY to just be the **room_code** column as it then has to be unique.

If the **room_code** column will/may not be unique and that the only guaranteed uniqueness will be the **room_code** column and the **lang_code** column combined. The you would need to define a composite foreign key (refer to link above).